# Determine if its triangle javascript code issue / beginner

Tags: javascript

This piece of code suppose to determine if three side lengths are triangle,
however something went wrong and I cannot understand what as I believe that logic is there ...

Could anyone have a look into this code and put me on the right track please  ...also I wonder why I cannot assign array with elements as a function parameter like :

`function isTriangle(arrAline[i]`....etc ?

I am absolutely beginner and it confuses me a lot :D

```
let arrAline = [474, 431, 372, 1887, 1064, 3212, 1057];
let arrBline = [684, 623, 525, 548, 573, 1328, 2376];
let arrCline = [1339, 709, 1179, 881, 304, 956, 959];

let i = 0;

function isTriangle(arrAline, arrBline, arrCline) {
  for (i = 0; i < arrAline.length; i++) {
    if (arrAline[i] + arrBline[i] > arrCline[i] && arrAline[i] + arrCline[i] > arrBline[i] && arrCline[i] + arrBline[i] > arrAline[i]) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
};
isTriangle(arrAline[i], arrBline[i], arrCline[i]);


//a + b > c
//a + c > b
//c + b > a
```

Thanks !

Comment: *"something went wrong"*: that is a very vague problem statement. Can you be (much) more clear?

Comment: it doesn't work on numbers which are in arrays, I would say that it doesn't pick any numbers ...

Comment: The call to `isTriangle` is incorrect.  Put the full arrays as parameters: `isTriangle(arrAline, arrBline, arrCline);`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you mix up the use of `i`. Either you define `i` locally in the function, and don't use it in the function call, or you move the loop outside of the function, into the main code.

If you go for the first approach, then the problem is that you (1) don't pass the arrays as function arguments, and (2) always `return` in the `for` loop.

You are supposed to iterate *all* entries, whatever the outcome, and not just exit on the first iteration, leaving all other entries unvisited.

Instead you should *collect* the boolean results in a new array, and keep iterating, and then when all entries have been visited, return that result-array.

Side note: in this scenario, don't define `i` outside your function. It should be declared within the function as a local variable.

Here is how that could work:

```js
function isTriangle(arrAline, arrBline, arrCline) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arrAline.length; i++) {
    if (arrAline[i] + arrBline[i] > arrCline[i] && arrAline[i] + arrCline[i] > arrBline[i] && arrCline[i] + arrBline[i] > arrAline[i]) {
      result.push(true);
    } else {
      result.push(false);
    }
  }
  return result;
};


let arrAline = [474, 431, 372, 1887, 1064, 3212, 1057];
let arrBline = [684, 623, 525, 548, 573, 1328, 2376];
let arrCline = [1339, 709, 1179, 881, 304, 956, 959];
console.log(isTriangle(arrAline, arrBline, arrCline)); // don't use `i` here.
```

You can of course also go for the second approach, and then you don't need the `result` variable, but then also you don't use the function arguments as arrays, and move the `for` loop to the main code:

```js
function isTriangle(aline, bline, cline) {
    if (aline + bline > cline && aline + cline > cline && cline + bline > aline) {
         return true;
    } else {
         return false;
    }
};


let arrAline = [474, 431, 372, 1887, 1064, 3212, 1057];
let arrBline = [684, 623, 525, 548, 573, 1328, 2376];
let arrCline = [1339, 709, 1179, 881, 304, 956, 959];
for (let i = 0; i < arrAline.length; i++) {
    console.log(isTriangle(arrAline[i], arrBline[i], arrCline[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the first value of each array into the `isTriangle` function, pass the three array inside it and return the index which forms the triangle.

You can do like this:

```js
let arrAline = [474, 431, 372, 1887, 1064, 3212, 1057];
let arrBline = [684, 623, 525, 548, 573, 1328, 2376];
let arrCline = [1339, 709, 1179, 881, 304, 956, 959];

function isTriangle(arrAline, arrBline, arrCline) {
 let isTriangles = []
  for (i = 0; i < arrAline.length; i++) {
    if (arrAline[i] + arrBline[i] > arrCline[i] && arrAline[i] + arrCline[i] > arrBline[i] && arrCline[i] + arrBline[i] > arrAline[i]) {
      isTriangles.push(true);
    } else {
      isTriangles.push(false);
    }
  }
  
  return isTriangles
};

checkTriangles = isTriangle(arrAline, arrBline, arrCline)
console.log('the triangles are at index ',checkTriangles.flatMap((bool, index) => bool ? index : []))
```

Hope it helps :)